Redirect same port from NIC to localhost using iptables
I have a service that listens only on a port on localhost. In this case TCP 6464. This machine splits traffic between a NIC (eth0) and a VPN (tun0) interface, while some ports only listen on localhost (lo). Is it possible, using iptables, to start listening on TCP port 6464 on eth0 and forward that to TCP 6464 on lo? I have been able to do it with socat, but iptables would be preferable since all the other rules are defined there.
Here is the socat cmd:
sudo socat TCP-LISTEN:6464,fork,bind=<IP of eth0> TCP:127.0.0.1:6464

I have tried different examples found online but not been successful.
Thanks!

Try sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1, sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6464 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:6464

@user202311 answer looks good but it is missing the detail that only traffic from eth0 supposed to dnat-ed to localhost:6464. So: sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6464 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:6464

Thanks. I have tried these variants but unfortunately they did not work... Next step for me is to turn on logging in iptables and see where the packets go.
